# Allowing only certain characters in string in vb6

Tags: vb6, textbox, restrict

I wanna make only predefined characters to be able to used on my textbox in vb6.
How can i achive that?

Predefined characters will be like `0-9` and `A, C, M, E` all other characters besides these gonna give a msgbox as err. it can also be `a,c,m,e` i can use `Ucase()` to solve it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can;

```
private Sub atextbox_KeyPress(keyascii As Integer)
   if InStr(1, "0123456789ACME", Chr$(keyascii)) = 0 Then keyascii  = 0 '//case sensitive
End Sub
```

or

```
if Chr$(keyascii) like "[0-9]" or Chr$(keyascii) like "[ACMEacme]"
```

alternatively formatted

```
select case true
    case chr$(keyascii) like "[0-9]"
    case chr$(keyascii) like "[ACMEacme]"
    case else
        keyascii = 0
end select
```

Comment: `case chr$(keyascii) like "[0-9]"`
    `case chr$(keyascii) like "[ACMEacme]"`
thats kinda thing that i ve been looking for thank you xD

Comment: Aren't you going to swallow `Tab` and `Shift-Tab` if you do this?

Comment: Tab, arrows, home etc should be ok as they wont raise the event, although a `case keyascii=vbKeyBack` is probably advisable

Answer (score 5):

You can detect each character entered using the `KeyPress` event and checking the ASCII value. If you set it to 0, the press will be ignored.
Be sure to also check in the `Change` event to catch pasting, etc.

Also, don't use a messagebox as this will annoy users.

Comment: thats the idea! annoying users that does it wrong while i told them not to use other than defined characters.. xD

Comment: Well spotted about pasting, etc. I'd be inclined to put the check in the Change event only, for that reason.

Comment: Only problem with Change only is if they type an out of range character and it's removed, it forces the carat back to the beginning. (My code does this at the moment which winds my colleagues up :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the [KeyPress](http://visualbasic.freetutes.com/learn-vb6-advanced/lesson5/p2.html) event:

```
Private Sub txtBox_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
    Dim KeyChar As String
    If KeyAscii > 31 Then 'ignore low-ASCII characters like BACKSPACE
        KeyChar = Chr(KeyAscii)

        If Not IsAllowed(KeyChar) Then
          KeyAscii = 0
          MsgBox.Show("The allowed characters are ... ")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

The IsAllowed function will contain the allowed key codes.

Comment: Using IsNumeric and keeping the allowed character values in an array of Integers should keep it concise.